# SAP .NET Connector problem in c# not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022, sap-dotnet-connector

According to article Step by step tutorial to use SAP .NET Connector with VS 2008 [closed], I tried to connect and run a query. In VS Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 it is not working.

Unable to start connection to SAP software with SAP .NET Connector.

Thank you for any help !

> System.InvalidCastException
> HResult=0x80004002
> Nachricht = Das Objekt des Typs "SAP_Connect.ECCDestinationConfig" kann nicht in Typ "SAP.Middleware.Connector.IDestinationConfiguration" umgewandelt werden.

Code:

```
ECCDestinationConfig cfg = new ECCDestinationConfig();

RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration((IDestinationConfiguration)cfg);

RfcDestination dest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mySAPdestination");

RfcRepository repo = dest.Repository;

IRfcFunction testfn = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_XBP_REPORT_SEARCH");

testfn.Invoke(dest);

var companyCodeList = testfn.GetTable("REPORTS");
```

Comment: it looks like you use the wrong version on NCo connector, try to download the latest one and check if it matches x62/x32 of VS